# How can I get an event when an audio file reaches a certain point?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am experimenting with interactive audio applications in HTML, and I would like to be able to seamlessly start playing one audio file just as another audio file reaches a particular playback location; for example, if audio file A is playing, then I would like to receive an event when it reaches 16 seconds in exactly.

I have tried using `audio.play(); setTimeout(myCallback, 16000);` for this, but I am finding it to be incredibly unstable in some browsers (Safari especially, particularly when the window is in the background), and will sometimes fire slightly early, and other times fire very late. This remains the case even if I explicitly stop, rewind, and `.load()` the upcoming audio segment when scheduling the callback.

My current (simple) looper that simply toggles between two players every 16 seconds is below:

```
audio = []
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    audio[i] = new Audio("mew" + i + ".mp3");
}
var which = 0;
var pump = function() {
    audio[which].play();
    which = (which + 1) % audio.length;
    window.setTimeout(pump, 16000);
}
audio[which].addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    pump();
});
for (i in audio) {
    audio[i].load();
}
```

Also, note that while in this case I could use `setInterval()`, that will not always be the case (and anyway, `setInterval()` suffers from the same stability problem).

Comment: Have you looked at the [MDN Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) page?  In particular, the [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event looks promising...

Comment: Hm, the references I was looking at indicate that `timeupdate` is fired when the user affects the playback time, not when the play head moves on its own. I'll try it out anyway, though, thanks.

Comment: @anied Okay, just tried it, and in Safari it does continuously update, but unfortunately not with enough precision.

Comment: ah, sorry, thought it might be worth a try.

Comment: Sure, it was a reasonable thought. :)